# Each class create static fields for themselves in C code (NDK)

Tags: android, c, static, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm kind of new in C and NDK and in my app I want to save and share some data between different files. So I make .c file which contains static field.

When I use it in one file it work great, but when I try to use it in other file it doesn't have data which I wrote there before. It looks every single file create new instance of my static fields inside themselves

**EDIT**

Added .h file.

Code test.h:

```
#ifndef IJKPLAYER_TEST_H
#define IJKPLAYER_TEST_H

void saveStartLoadingData();

int64_t getStartLoading();

void addToLoadingByte(int64_t bytesCount);

void endOfLoading();

void calculateAndSaveCurrentBitrate();

int64_t getDiff();

int64_t getLoadedBites();

int64_t getEndLoading();

int64_t getCurrentBitrate();

#endif //IJKPLAYER_TEST_H
```

test.c:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <time.h>

static const int64_t ONE_SECOND= 1000000000LL;

extern int64_t start_loading;
extern int64_t end_loading ;
extern int64_t loaded_bytes;
extern int64_t currentBitrate;
extern int64_t diff;

int64_t now_ms() {
    struct timespec now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
    return (int64_t) now.tv_sec*1000000000LL + now.tv_nsec;
}

void saveStartLoadingData(){
    loaded_bytes = 0LL;
    start_loading =  now_ms();
}

int64_t getStartLoading(){
    return start_loading;
}

void addToLoadingByte(int64_t bytesCount){
    loaded_bytes += bytesCount;
}

void endOfLoading(){
    end_loading = now_ms();
    diff = end_loading - start_loading;
}

void calculateAndSaveCurrentBitrate(){
    currentBitrate = loaded_bytes * ONE_SECOND/ diff;
    loaded_bytes = 0;
}

int64_t getDiff(){
    return diff;
}
int64_t getLoadedBites(){
    return loaded_bytes;
}
int64_t getEndLoading(){
    return end_loading;
}
int64_t getCurrentBitrate(){
    return currentBitrate;
}
```

And now I include this to other file in this way:

```
#include "test.h"
```

**EDIT 2**

New error

```
libavformat/avio.c:430: error: undefined reference to 'getStartLoading'
libavformat/avio.c:431: error: undefined reference to 'getEndLoading'
libavformat/avio.c:432: error: undefined reference to 'getLoadedBites'
```

Comment: C does not have classes. It is no OOPL.

Comment: @Olaf sorry I mean file

Comment: Variables like `int64_t start_loading;` are now missing in your test.c file. Add them again. I said that you had to remove `static`. Not the whole line. Please reread what i said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only allowed to inlude a .c file one time.

If you need to use the variables or functions from that .c file in another .c or .cpp file you have to make a .h file and include that in the file where you need the variables. You can include a .h file in as many .c or .cpp files as you want.

In the .h file write:

```
extern int64_t start_loading;
void saveStartLoadingData();
```

Remove all `static`from the .c file.

Comment: Ok I created .h file with field and .c files(I edited the question, there's code of .h .c), but I faced with two problems when compile my code. First: in place where method calls I have this error "error: undefined reference to" Second: if I remove all methods and left only fields and try to use them from other files I receive "error: undefined reference to"

Comment: Please give complete example for your first error. And give complete error message.

Comment: Where did you include the .c file? Or did you add it to the project?

Comment: I added new error in question too, but it's very short.  I didn't do some specific things to connect .c I just created it with the same name and add #include "test.h" in the top of it.

Comment: You should of course let the test.c file compile to. So add it to your project. Or include it in one of your other files. I said that before but you are nog reacting.

Comment: I returned fields to .c file and add my classes to Makefile. But compiler returns to me this error: "error: undefined reference to my_field" inside of test.c file. So I tried to remove "extern" and now I don't have any errors. I tested it and all files work with same data. So it that what I wanted to. But is it work correct? Because as I understood, it has to work in this way(same data in different files) only with "extern"

Comment: What you have now is wrong. In the .c file it should be `int64_t start_loading;` and in the .h file `extern int64_t start_loading;`.